# gnuplot: how to set error bars and label simultaneously

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot

I want to plot a curve that has error bars. I used `with yerrorlines` for that.

Now I want to show a label for each point that should be done by: `with labels`

How can I use both of them simultaneously? I tried `with yerrorlines ,labels` but not worked!

Comment: At the gnuplot tag we don't have such crazy response times...

Answer (score 0):

You must plot the data twice:

```
plot 'data' using 1:2:3 with yerrorlines title 'title',\
        '' using 1:2:4 with labels offset 0,2 notitle
```

You must probably adapt the label offset such that the label it doesn't overlap with the error bars.